# Как добавить объект,а не перезаписать его?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, backend

```
 User.updateOne({email: email}, {$set: {"categories": x}}, function (err, result) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        console.log(result);
    });
```

Comment: Так это же именно апдейт метод. Есть `save()`, он пишет новый объект в базу. [Вот дока](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно вас понял, вы хотите добавить объект `x` в массив `categories`. Тогда вам нужен оператор `$push`:

```
User.updateOne({email: email}, {$push: {"categories": x}}, function (err, result) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Я хочу добавить объект x в объект categories.Пуш работает только на массивы .

Comment: @kekik Смержить два объекта или добавить как внутреннее проперти? Можно пример результата до и после?

Comment: Есть объект, в котором содержатся еще объекты.Надо добавить туда объект.
` categories: {
                    nature: {},
                    animals: {}
                                   }"`
Все как вы написали, только categories это объект, а не массив

Comment: Допустим у вас был объект {categories: {nature: {}} и вы хотите добавить в него объект {animals: {}}. Вы можете послать что-то вроде: User.updateOne({email: email}, {$set: {"categories.animals": x}}. Так вы установите у объекта "categories" субпроперти "animals".

Comment: Но, если вы хотите послать что-то типо: User.updateOne({email: email}, {$someOp: {"categories": {"animals": {}}}} и ожидаете, что Mongo запихнет "animals" и все возможные проперти внутри этого объекта во внутрь "categories", то не думаю что на данный момент это возможно

Comment: Спасибо, вот что мне надо было {$set: {"categories.animals": x}}